# Ctrl-C behavior in gnome-terminal

Tags: shell, gnome, ubuntu-10.04, gnome-terminal, characters

I have installed Ubuntu 10.04. It works fine, but when I press Ctrl-C in gnome-terminal I get:

```
user@desktop:~$ ^C
user@desktop:~$ ^C
user@desktop:~$
```

In Ubuntu 9.04 (I did have it before) it was so:

```
user@desktop:~$ 
user@desktop:~$ 
user@desktop:~$
```

Who knows how can I fix this?

Comment: i expect, best case, this is due to an obscure *bash* (or possibly *gconf*) setting; medium case, this is due to some tweak in a *terminfo* file; worst case, you'll have to patch code and recompile your *bash* or *gnome-terminal* packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a try, it will affect other control characters, too:

```
stty -echoctl
```

Comment: Dennis, thanks a lot. It works. But when I close gnome-terminal and run it again this parametr is on. How can I save it?

Comment: @sev: Add that command to your `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: You should make that only run when you're on a terminal, with something like: `[ -t 1 ] && stty -echoctl`

Comment: @NVRAM: I'm curious what the downside is. Besides, normally `~/.bashrc` is only loaded for interactive shells.

Comment: Hmm, I think you're right. *If it's in `~/.bashrc` rather than `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`* -- it would be good to add that to the answer.   While it would probably not kill the job (just print an unneeded error) it's a habit I picked up using Bourne and K-shells -- to avoid interactive commands for when the profile was run by `cron` or `at` jobs.

Answer (score 0):

you can also highlight and use right click on systems you access but don't want to or have time to change settings.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key down as well. So instead of just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, you do <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.